# Unit test angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-controller

I've been looking through countless SO post on this but can't get the unit test of my angular controller to work.

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CorrMatrixCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/ng/areq?p0=CorrMatrixCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at /home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/app/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (/home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1402:11)
    at assertArgFn (/home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1412:3)
    at /home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6881:9
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:28:20)
    at Object.invoke (/home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/app/lib/angular/angular.js:3762:17)
    at workFn (/home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:2144:20)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:2129:25)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:26:33)
    at /home/sebastian/gutenberg-for-good/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:1:1
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('gutenberg.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('CorrMatrixCtrl', ['AnalysisFactory', '$scope', function(AnalysisFactory, $scope){

    $scope.get = function() {
        //something
    };

}]);
```

**Test:**

```
describe("corrMatrixCtrl test", function() {

    var fakeFactory = {
        // some code
    };

    beforeEach(angular.module("gutenberg.controllers"));

    it("should have a get method", inject(function($controller, $rootScope) { // line 26

        var controller = $controller("CorrMatrixCtrl", {AnalysisFactory: fakeFactory, $scope: $rootScope.$new()}); // line 28

        expect(angular.isFunction(controller.get)).toBe(true);
    }));

});
```

From all the tutorials I've been reading or watching and all the documentation I can't see the error. Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

**Karma config:**

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
    basePath : '../',

    files : [
      'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
      'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
      'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/js/**/*.js',
      'test/unit/controllersSpec.js'
    ],

    exclude : [
      'app/lib/angular/angular-loader.js',
      'app/lib/angular/*.min.js',
      'app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js'
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    plugins : [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine'
            ],

})}
```

Comment: What if you remove the dependency on ui.bootstrap?

Comment: Also, I think you're misusing the it statement.  As far as I know, it expects a function as the second parameter.  Instead, you're passing the return value of the inject function, which is probably undefined.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using the inject function is this case is correct, since in [Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/test/unit/controllersSpec.js) it's done the same way. The dependency is necessary since i'm using Angular UI Bootstrap, although I realized that in [another tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/unit-and-e2e-testing-in-angularjs/) I tried without UI Bootstrap the injection works. But I don't see any cause in UI Bootstrap, especially since there's [no issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues?state=open) reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your defining the `get` method on the $scope, and not on the controller. So your test should be:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
var controller = $controller("CorrMatrixCtrl", {AnalysisFactory: fakeFactory, $scope: scope});
expect(angular.isFunction(scope.get)).toBe(true);
```

If you wanted to define it on the controller, your controller code should be:

```
this.get = function() {
    //something
};
```

That probably doesn't solve your problem though. My guess is that you don't include the controller code in the test. Add an alert/console.log at the top of the controller file and rerun the test to make sure that it's there.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the controller is missing and after adding console log there's no output in console, but I don't get WHY it is missing.

Comment: How are you running your tests? From Karma or just the browser?

Comment: I'm using karma. Debug logs show that all necessary files are included.

Comment: If that's the case then the controller code might get included after the tests are executed. Could you update your post with your karma config file?

Comment: Added the config file, but I think the test get included last.

Comment: What's the path to your controller file?

Comment: app/js/controller.js - I tried adding it explicitly but it's still not found

Comment: Try changing `beforeEach(angular.module("gutenberg.controllers"));` to `beforeEach(module("gutenberg.controllers"));`.

Comment: It works, but why does ``angular.`` has to be removed? The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) says it can be used to retrieve modules as well. Which function are we calling when ``angular.`` is omitted?

Comment: It's because module == angular.mock.module and not angular.module. Same as inject == angular.mock.inject.